# Using an angular 6 library in html and plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-library

I am trying creating an angular 6 library. The library builds properly and i can see the following folders as output:
bundles
esm5
esm2015
fesm5
fesm2015
lib

I question is, is it possible to simply import the js file built from here and use it in plain-old javascript and html.
The libraries generated through ng build seems to have dependencies on angular/core